# Why there are too many gpus in docker container?

Tags: docker, nvidia

There is 4 GPUs on my host mahchine

```
[root@c3-sa-i2-20151229-buf023 ~]# nvidia-smi
Wed Jul 12 14:27:40 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P8    21W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P8    22W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:83:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0   105W / 235W |   8336MiB / 11439MiB |     94%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:84:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P8    22W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    2      4148    C   python                                        8330MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In docker inspect,I only used 2 GPUs.

```
"Devices": [
            {
                "PathOnHost": "/dev/nvidiactl",
                "PathInContainer": "/dev/nvidiactl",
                "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
            },
            {
                "PathOnHost": "/dev/nvidia-uvm",
                "PathInContainer": "/dev/nvidia-uvm",
                "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
            },
            {
                "PathOnHost": "/dev/nvidia0",
                "PathInContainer": "/dev/nvidia0",
                "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
            },
            {
                "PathOnHost": "/dev/nvidia1",
                "PathInContainer": "/dev/nvidia1",
                "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
            },
            {
                "PathOnHost": "/dev/fuse",
                "PathInContainer": "/dev/fuse",
                "CgroupPermissions": "mrw"
            }
        ],
```

But I can see 4 GPUs in my container.

```
root@de-3879-ng-1-021909-1176603283-2jpbx:/notebooks# ls /dev | grep nv
nvidia-uvm
nvidia-uvm-tools
nvidia0
nvidia1
nvidia2
nvidia3
nvidiactl

root@de-3879-ng-1-021909-1176603283-2jpbx:/tmp# ./nvidia-smi 
Wed Jul 12 06:31:57 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P8    21W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P8    22W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:83:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   41C    P0    98W / 235W |   8336MiB / 11439MiB |     66%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla K40m          Off  | 0000:84:00.0     Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P8    22W / 235W |      0MiB / 11439MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Can I get the device mapping info in docker container?**

ex.

host /dev/nvidia0-> container /dev/nvidia0

**Can I believe docker inspect info?**